# heading tags not displaying in IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

At http://ginc.brokencogsolutions.com/ we are building a demo site for someone but h1, h2, etc. do not show up in IE.

Does this have something to do with my styling? I dont think it's a font issue, but I could be wrong there. This seems to be the only discrepancy so far that I've found.

http://ginc.brokencogsolutions.com/css/style.css is the stylesheet if anyone cares to look at it and guide me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fginc.brokencogsolutions.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thank you for this! I always forget about the validator. I'll work on correcting these. By some of these, i'm surprised to see it looking as good as it does on other browsers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem with cufon. why you using cufon , please use font face

Comment: I thought it might have to do something with cufon. but having used it on other sites alright, i wasn't sure. Perhaps it was the font family chosen.